# Is there anyway to end the program without using break?

Tags: python

I got a program when input a number they show some command and when i put in number 4 i want it print goodbye and end the program. I know there is a way is use break but my teacher dont want to use it . Is there any other way to end it when enter number 4 ? Thank in advance : 
PS : i just new leaner to Python.

```
while True  :
     num= int(input("enter : "))

    if num == 1:
       print("encrypt text")
    elif num == 2 :
        print("decrypt text")
    elif num == 3 :
        print("Brute force decrypt")
    elif num ==4 :
        print("goodbye")
    else :
            print('false')
```

Comment: Use `sys.exit(0)`

Comment: @rdas That sounds more against-the-spirit than `break`

Comment: Instead of `while True`, you could do `while not done:` and set `done = True` when you want to quit. Realistically, this isn't as elegant as a break, though...

Comment: Not being allowed to use a language feature is more against-the-spirit IMO

Comment: Another idea is to extract your code into a separate function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### 1. Use a variable in the while condition:

```
num = 0
while num != 4:
    num = int(input("enter : "))    
    ... your other code
```

### 2. Raise an exception:

```
try:
    while True:
        num = int(input("enter : "))    
        ... your other code
        elif num == 4:
            raise StopIteration 
        ...
except StopIteration as e:
     print('goodbye')
```

### 3. Put it inside a function and return:

```
def main():
    while True:
        num = int(input("enter : "))    
        ... your other code
        elif num == 4:
            return
        ...
main()
print('goodbye')
```

### 4. Exit the program:

```
while True:
    num = int(input("enter : "))
    ... your other code
    elif num ==4 :
        print("goodbye")
    
        # Do any of the following
        exit()
        quit()
        raise SystemExit
        sys.exit() # requires "import sys"
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! This will help a lot

Comment: Good to hear @Shay. If you think this answer led to solving your problem, you can mark your question as resolved. To know more, check the following link out https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2):

A simple way could be:

```
number = 0
while number != 4:
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

To exit:

```
import sys
sys.exit(0)
```

If you need to break nested loops, you can put your code inside a function and then use "return None" instead of "break"

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am also new to the platform of python but I have the answer to your question. You can use:

```
import sys          
sys.exit(0)
```

Well, I hope that this might help you. ☺

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We like to keep answers to the point, so I recommend you don't include things like "If you like it then do up vote. Thank You!" - just stick to the answer.